# UL alignment to bottom

Tags: css

Profile Pictures
    1 Picture
    

     
     
     
    
     Profile Pictures
     2 Picture

css for is as bellow.

```
     #album{
height:195px;
width:155px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:6px 10px 14px 10px;
    float:left;

  }
#album li{
    border:0; 
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 0.15em;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline;
   }

   #album img{
  vertical-align:bottom;
   }
    #album a{
        color:#000000;
        text-decoration:none;

    }
    #album .user-title{
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-bottom:4px;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#36538D;
    }
    #album .addas{
        display:block;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#666666;
    }
    #album img{
        margin-right:14px;
        padding:4px;

    }
```

this is working fine.

but i need to align images to bottom on display.

[here is image](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/6586/84829763.jpg)

Comment: Your question makes little sense. They're already at bottom. Don't you rather mean "align text to top"? If not, please illustrate how the final result should look like.

Comment: It's worth mentioning only one element can have an id on any particular page. "list1" should be a class. You can have as many classes on a page as you like.

Comment: try <img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="google.jpg" height="50"/>, is this what you mean ?

Comment: i have added image to it, how result is showing in browser and how i want.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an easy solution to align all `<li>` contents to bottom in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/EmGqZ/

```
<style>
      ul#album {
        list-style-type: none;
    } #album li {
        float: left;
    }
    li div {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 415px;
        display: table-cell;
    }​
</style>

<ul id="album">
    <li><div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/windows-8-metro/96/Drives-B-Metro-icon.png" /> 
        </a>
        <p><a href="#">Profile Pictures</a></p>
        <p>1 Picture</p>
    </div></li>

    <li><div style="padding-left: 15px">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dakirby309/windows-8-metro/128/Drives-A-Metro-icon.png" /> 
        </a>
        <p><a href="#">Profile Pictures</a></p>
        <p>1 Picture</p>
    </div></li>
</ul>​
```

The main detail here is `display: table-cell;` declaration in css for all the divs located inside of li elements.

PS I think it is a bad idea to use the same id many times. But I suppose it was a misprint.

Comment: Wow, a reply to a 1.5 year old post. I hope the OP is still looking for an answer.

Comment: I suppose it might be useful for anybody who can try to look for the answer at any time. StackOverflow is kind of knowledge base, isn't it?

Comment: 1 year later, the young apprentice stumbles upon this, and exclaims "AHHHHHH!" -- thanks :)

Comment: @NRGdallas I've also added a jsfiddle example. Hope 3 more thousand of visitors have also got some help from this topic :) Thanks a million to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I see the screenshot and now it's clear what you mean. Your initial example was far from valuable, it was incomplete. I copypasted it and I see all li's below each other, all perfectly aligned at bottom. You should have created a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) which reproduces exactly the problem you have. Thus, from `<html>` to `</html>` including the doctype and the minimum required styles.

Now I'm guessing, but it look like that you have used `float: left;` on the `li` elements instead of `display: inline;` to display them next each other (inline) instead of below each other (block). The floats are by default aligned to top of the containing element and the display-inline is by default aligned to bottom of the containing element. Fix it accordingly and see if that helps in your case.

Comment: its same even i add display:inline; 
i also include full css in page.
thanks

Comment: @BalusC - just had a similar issue. I changed float:left; by display:inline; on li elements, and on those same elements I applied vertical-align: bottom; on those li elements. It worked like a charm. Thanks for keeping this.